# Confused with JSON string returned by webservice

Tags: ajax, json, kendo-ui

I just started to play around with Kendo-UI, web services and JSON. First I created and deployed my asp.net web service (I did not plan to use WCF). I checked the ASMX file which returned the following result:

```
[
{"Id":"4e7dc3f8-db50-4978-be10-09808a6216a7","CompanyName":"company1"},
{"Id":"d156a2cd-1768-439e-98eb-134366a6c9be","CompanyName":"company2"},
{"Id":"7acba8b5-b773-4071-bfd5-2537d7d20e1e","CompanyName":"company3"}
]
```

I checked the above result with a web based JSON validator (copy/paste, not via calling the web service), which resulted in a successful parsing. So far everything seemed to be OK.

The next step was to populate a kendoDropDownList with the results:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {                    
            url: "/scws/qpm.asmx/GetSuppliers",
            dataType: "json"
        }
    }
});

$("#supplier").kendoDropDownList({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    dataValueField: "Id",
    dataTextField: "CompanyName"            
});
```

Well, it did not work. I tried several variations, until I gave up and tried to call my web service a different way, just for testing:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/scws/qpm.asmx/GetSuppliers",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",            
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function (msg) {
            // data is returned                                                      

        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            // handle error
            alert(status);
            alert(xhr.status);                
            alert(xhr.responseText);
            alert(error);
        }
    });
```

Well, I got a parser error (200). The response text is different from what I got with directly testing the ASMX file. The response text seems to be longer:

```
[
    {"Id":"4e7dc3f8-db50-4978-be10-09808a6216a7","CompanyName":"company1"},
    {"Id":"d156a2cd-1768-439e-98eb-134366a6c9be","CompanyName":"company2"},
    {"Id":"7acba8b5-b773-4071-bfd5-2537d7d20e1e","CompanyName":"company3"}
] 
{"d":null}
```

I am sure I did some basic thing very badly... I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not know what your asmx method looks like, it's hard to say exactly.  Here is a quick sample asmx I threw together.  I did go ahead and switch my method to use a GET instead of a POST.

Webservice

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod (UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public List<Person> GetPeople()
    {
        List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
        people.Add(new Person() { Age = 21, Name = "Fred" });
        people.Add(new Person() { Age = 31, Name = "Ted" });
        people.Add(new Person() { Age = 41, Name = "Ned" });
        people.Add(new Person() { Age = 51, Name = "Red" });


        return people;
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Which returned this json

```
{"d":[{"__type":"ASMXTest.Person","Name":"Fred","Age":21},{"__type":"ASMXTest.Person","Name":"Ted","Age":31},{"__type":"ASMXTest.Person","Name":"Ned","Age":41},{"__type":"ASMXTest.Person","Name":"Red","Age":51}]}
```

Here is my kendo dataSource to access that webmethod

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "Service.asmx/GetPeople",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                }
            },
            schema: {
                data: function (response) {
                    return response.d;
                }
            }
        });

        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: dataSource,
            columns: [
                { field: 'Name' },
                { field: 'Age' }
            ]
        });
```

If this doesn't get you going, please post your asmx webmethod.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help and time. I am afraid the problem was with my webservice. Now its fine.